# How do I install dual boot properly?? Last attempt corrupted MBR completely

Tags: dual-boot

Dell Inspiron n5110 with i5, 4gb Ram, 500gb HDD Windows 7 and UBUNTU 12.04.4.  I booted off a Live USB and everything was great.  I really want UBUNTU so I tried to do a dual install using the included install app.  I selected 50gb space, and ran the install.  Everything was great until I re-booted.  Then I got an error message saying there was no such Device (?) and completely crashing.  I had to boot of the live USB again to get anything to work at all.  I then deleted the two partitions created during the install, rebooted using a HIRENS USB stick, which got me back into Windows.  I then created a system repair disk and re-booted again with the cd.  I was able to repair the MBR after that and finally get Windows to boot normally.

BUT... I still want to install UBUNTU 12.04.4 if I can figure out what went wrong and get it to work properly.  Any advice????

Additional information..
Thanks for the reply but no go with that.  I just tried to install 13.10 and the install said I there was no OP system detected. In other words, I could not detect Windows 7 (after I repaired the MBR) Yet I can boot Windows 7 normally.  This is very frustrating.  I know UBUNTU is working because I can boot from a live USB with no problem and run in trial mode all day.  But of course, can't add aps and save it in trial mode.  I want to install so I can add GNURADIO for some radio astronomy projects.  My other option is to use PENTOO Unix but I'd prefer to stick with UBUNTU.

Answer (score 1):

When I ran Ubuntu and Kali in a dual boot, I took off about 60 gigs (you might want more or less than that, don't go lower than 20) from my hard driver into it's own free space, then I just installed onto the free space and I never had a problem with it.

Ubuntu has an option to install alongside Windows that should work.

Try formatting the USB and try again using UNETbootin.

http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/

Select install alongside Windows first, if that doesn't work, then choose "something else" and take a small chunk off the hard driver for free space.

After re-reading the post, I'm thinking maybe your Ubuntu download got corrupted?

Re download here if that's the case. http://www.ubuntu.com/download

Then burn the ISO to a dvd at the slowest speed possible or using UNETbootin is safer also. I also hear torrenting is safer rather than direct download, so you could try that.

I hope you get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I read about dual booting nowdays, especially with the tack MS has taken with boot issues, my first thought is to wonder why? By installing a virtual machine manager you can run as many operating systems as you want, and run them at the same time. Using vmware you could even have gnuradio running right on your windows desktop (or have windows running on your gnu desktop).

Comment: Tried using wubi which creates a virtual install (I read up on it) but doesn't work.  I **DO** get a menu with Windows 7 first and UBUNTU second, but when I click on UBUNTU it executes about 3 commands so fast I can't read the screen then comes up with the GRUB> prompt and sits there.  The windows selection boots windows just fine.  I tried uninstall and re-install several times with exactly the same result.  I also tried to get a verbose run of the grub but no luck there either. (boo hoo).

Comment: Wubi is not virtualization software. Wubi just creates a loop device mount point so you don't have to repartition your drive. Frankly, I can see where wubi could lead to more complications than using a dual boot, although most seem to have no issue with it. Install vmware, virtualbox or something similar and install it there.